# Putting string after a where clause in a soql query in salesforce

Tags: string, salesforce

I have the filter logic parsed and put as a string in a variable called "where_clause". I have to use this where_clause in a query to fetch data.How can I use a string of this type after the where part of the query?I am working on salesforce with custom objects.

Comment: Could you provide the SOQL you're using as your base query, and the contents of the variable "where_clause"? It's difficult to tell what you're trying to do with only the description.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check [Dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm).
In particular

```
String myTestString = 'TestName';
List<sObject> sobjList = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM MyCustomObject__c WHERE Name = :myTestString');
```

If you have your Custom Object as MyCustomObject__c

```
String myTestString = 'TestName';
List<MyCustomObject__c> sobjList = (List<MyCustomObject__c>)Database.query('SELECT Id FROM MyCustomObject__c WHERE Name = :myTestString');
```